# Pointers to structures in C++ - reading from console?

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, cin, cout

I have a program, where I want to read information about books, organised in structure - for example read the author from the console and then print it on the standard output as written below. However the Visual Studio compiler (IDE) gives an error - `this declaration has no storage class or type specifier`, when I try to assign to the pointer the adress of the structure : `ptstr = &a;` I would like to ask what am I doing the wrong way?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
struct Book {
    string title;
    string author;
    string price;

};
Book a;
Book *ptstr;
ptstr = &a;
int main()
{


    cin >> ptstr->author;
    cout << ptstr->author;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Put `ptstr = &a;` in a function.

Comment: Or say `Book *ptstr = &a` instead of the two-line init you have there. My C++ is rusty, but I think the problem is that when you say `Book* ptstr; ptstr = &a;`, you're trying to put run-time code outside of any runnable function. If you say `Book* ptstr = &a`, you're telling the compiler to set some static variables before the program formally starts running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ptstr = &a;
```

This is invalid, as you are not allowed to assign to a variable in global scope. To fix this, change the declaration to:

```
Book *ptstr = &a;
```

You could also just move the assignment to `main`. The best advice here would be to just not use global variables and move both objects to `main`.

[Live Example](https://repl.it/@ArnavBorborah/ClosedColorlessSnake)